# Windows 7 won't wake when opening lid

Tags: windows-7, power, power-management

I've got a Samsung Series 5 laptop running Windows 7 SP1 Home Premium, fully patched.

It used to wake up from sleep by opening the lid, when I would *put it to* sleep by closing the lid. Unfortunately something seems to have changed recently, and after closing the lid, opening the lid does not wake it up anymore.

Recent changes to the system include updating the Elan Touchpad driver, updating the Realtek audio driver, installing a few pieces of software development packages, and toggling between power plans.

I also opened up one of the power plans and looked through each and every setting, and couldn't find anything related to *opening* the lid. The only power option that seems to be available in the context of the lid, is what action should be taken when the lid is *closed.*

**Question**: How do I get the lid to wake up the system again?

By the way, here is some information that might be useful. It enumerates the list of devices that can wake the system. I don't see the LCD panel listed in here.

```
PS C:\> powercfg -devicequery wake_programmable
Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6230
```